# how to add web reference to eclipse like you do in visual studio

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services

Is there a way to add web reference to Android Application in Eclipse like you add it in Visual Studio? I am trying like the old vay, craeting an envelope and send everything but I am having a problem. I just wonder if there is a way to add web service reference to eclipse like you do in visual studio